# How do I retrieve the tags on a class using YARD filters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yard

I'm really new to this, and I've been going through the [YARD docs](http://rubydoc.info/docs/yard/YARD/CodeObjects/ClassObject), and haven't really been able to figure out a solution to my problem.

Here is the code I'm starting with: https://github.com/spape/yard-rest-plugin which works great, but I'm trying to add some functionality to it.

Basically, I'm trying to add a filter such that I can include some Model documentation such that people looking through the Controller API docs can see what attributes of the Model they can use.

The plugin, yard-rest filters out any methods that don't have the `@resource` tag. So, I figured, I'd add a `@resource_object` tag, for my Models, that I want to show certain information about in the API docs.

In the plugin's code. I found in /lib/yard-rest.rb

```
YARD::Templates::Template.extra_includes << RestFilters
```

and in that file, I've modified the `reject_without_resource(list)` method

```
  def reject_without_resource(list)
    if list
      list.delete_if { |object| 
        if !object.is_a?(YARD::CodeObjects::ClassObject)
          true
        else
            !object.meths.detect{ |x| x.has_tag?(:resource) }# and 
          #  !object.detect{ |x| x.has_tag?(:resource_object) }
        end
      }
    end
  end
```

object is a `YARD::CodeObjects::ClassObject` in the cases that we care about. `object.meths` is an array of methods ([Method Objects](http://rubydoc.info/docs/yard/YARD/CodeObjects/MethodObject)). and the Method Objects have a detect method, which allows to test if a method has whatever tag we want to test for via the `.has_tag?` call.  But, I've been unable to find something similar for the class level. Right now, because I don't want to document any methods in the models for the API Docs, I don't want to put the @resource tag on any of the model methods.

My current .yardopts file, to show that I am indeed searching over models and controllers:

```
--title "My API Documentation"
--plugin rest
--readme API_README
app/models/*.rb
app/controllers/*.rb
```

So, how do I change the filter, such that I can include the models? Or at least class-level tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, you can call .has_tag on object.

If you just rearrange what you have to look like this:

```
def reject_without_resource(list)
    if list
      list.delete_if { |object|
        if object.has_tag?(:resource_object)
          false
        elsif object.meths.detect{ |x| x.has_tag? (:resource) }
          false
        else
          true
        end
      }
    end
  end
```

it will work